# mysql query behaving strangely?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a my sql query

```
INSERT INTO question (instruction_id, test_id, question,option1,option2,option3,option4,option5,option6,answer) VALUES ('0','1',' निम्न में से कौन सा मीडिया प्रकार सबसे अधिक जानकारी धारित कर सकता है? ','  ब्लू-रे    ',' सीडी    ',' डीवीडी ',' फ्लॉपी डिस्केट   ',' इनमें से कोई नहीं','','2')
```

I am running it from my application and from phpmyadmin. From my application options are not added everything before option1 and everything after option6 is getting added. But when i am running the query from phpmyadmin its working perfectly. What can be the possible reason for this issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are not setting the unicode references correctly in your php page, however phpmyadmin has it set correctly so it handles your characters. Use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

or set it in php using:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

You might also want to check on how to SET NAMES in mysql: `query("SET NAMES utf8");`

The basic thing to note is that when you are are working with unicode strings, you have to make sure that every aspect through which that data flows is unicode compliant so that it does not get lost anywhere in the pipeline.